# find a proper möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

What is the möbius transformation that maps from region 1 to region 2?

$R1=\{x|Re(x)>2 \text{ and }x\in \mathbb{C}\}$, $R2=\{x|x\in \mathbb{C} \text{ and }|x-i|>1\}$

My original homework was $R2=\{x|x\in \mathbb{C} \text{ and } |x-i|<1\}$, and I found $f(x)=4i/x$ but I wonder if a möbius transformation is exist for outside of the circle.

Comment: What is $C$—the complex plane? If so, there is no conformal mapping from the half-plane to the exterior of the circle, since the former region is simply connected but the latter region is not.

Comment: Do you mean "linear fractional map" or "Möbius transformation", by any chance? Because, as GregMartin points out, obviously there is no such linear map. Also the example you give is not linear, but linear fractional.

Comment: I am very sorry, I didn't know difference between the linear fractional map and möbius transformation and also wrongly wrote linear transform. But I mean möbius transformation. Can you please look again my question?